# exec ffmpeg stdout pipe stalling

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I've been trying to get the exec stdoutpipe from ffmpeg and write it into a different file. However, it stalls and doesn't finish executing the command.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func stdinfill(stdin io.WriteCloser) {
    fi, err := ioutil.ReadFile("music.ogg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewReader(fi))
}

func main() {
    runcommand()
}

func runcommand() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "pipe:0", "-f", "mp3", "pipe:1")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stdinfill(stdin)

    fo, err := os.Create("output.mp3")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    io.Copy(fo, stdout)

    defer fo.Close()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

does anyone have any ideas? It starts running ffmpeg but just stalls.

Comment: have you tried to close stdin after fill ? Otherwise it closes after Wait(), so if ffmpeg waits for its stdin to close before proceeding further, you will be blocked while reading its stdout.

Comment: @mh-cbon I have tried that (still stalls), thankfully now ffmpeg is saying it can't output to pipe:1 so the problem has to be something to do with stdout

Comment: try creating output.mpg before cmd.Start, and run `io.Copy(fo,stdout)` in a goroutine.

Comment: @bserdar changing when creating the file means the file actually gets created (yippee) and running io.copy whether in a goroutine or not still leads to a stall. When i exit out of ffmpeg i get `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Invalid argument` so i'm inclined to believe it's something to do with ffmpeg

Comment: Did you start the reader goroutine before wrting the input to the pipe?

Comment: @bserdar found the fix. i had to run the stdinfill in a goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Running stdinfill in a goroutine fixed the issue.